# Automate the send email test report of test cases using selenium and python

Tags: python

How do i automate send email test report to recipient from selenium webdriver using python. I'm currently using pycharm IDE to automate test cases.
I want send email to someone at last when this test case ran by me. Mail should have success and failed count. I tried to find the solution but failed.This is my test case. Please give me the solution.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from generic_functions.FindElement import HandyWrappers
from generic_functions.takescreenshots import Screenshot
from generic_functions.error_handle import CatchExceptions
import os
import time
import unittest

class TestHome(unittest.TestCase):
driverLocation = "C:\\Users\\Sales\\Desktop\\Automation\\ABCD\\libs\\chromedriver.exe"
os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = driverLocation
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driverLocation)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)    

def test_home(self):
    try:
        baseURL = "https://portal.abcd.com"
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get(baseURL)
        hw = HandyWrappers(driver)

        # regionLogin
        username = hw.getElement(".//form[@id='login-form']/fieldset/section[1]/label[2]/input[@name='email']",
                                 locatorType="xpath")
        username.send_keys("abcd@live.com")
        time.sleep(2)

        password = hw.getElement(".//form[@id='login-form']/fieldset/section[2]/label[2]/input[@name='password']",
                                 locatorType="xpath")
        password.send_keys("abcd")

        signIn = hw.getElement(".//form[@id='login-form']/footer/button[contains(text(),'Sign in')]",
                               locatorType="xpath")
        signIn.click()
        Screenshot.takeScreenshot(driver)
        # endregion
        time.sleep(2)

        driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0,300);")
        time.sleep(1)
        # Switch to Iframe from main page
        driver.switch_to.frame("ifrmClaimSummary")

        # regionScrolling Right and left
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(100,0);")
        time.sleep(1)
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(100,0);")
        time.sleep(1)
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(100,0);")
        time.sleep(1)

        # Scrolling Left
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(-100,0);")
        time.sleep(1)
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(-100,0);")
        time.sleep(1)
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(-100,0);")
        time.sleep(1)
        # endregion

        driver.switch_to.default_content()
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0,-300);")
        time.sleep(2)
        driver.quit()

    except Exception:
        CatchExceptions.PrintException()
        Screenshot.takeScreenshot(driver)


if __name__ == '__main__':
unittest.main()
```

Comment: You need to give more info...

Comment: I've briefly described the problem.

Comment: I see that you are logging in, then scrolling window a bunch, and then exiting. What part of this test should send mail? You aren't even trying to send anything...

Comment: Have you tried anything to send an email with test results? I.e., using `smtplib` to send mail, or are you asking for how to even approach doing that?

Comment: I don't know the approach for this. I don't know how to write test case in python which send mail of test report. @AndrewMorozko

Comment: I don't know the approach for this. I don't know how to write test case in python which send mail of test report. @Hawkins

Comment: This has nothing to do with selenium. You should start by googling send email with python and find some simple code to send an email and get that working. Once you have that, then come back and try to email some results. If you can't get it working, come back and post an [mcve] with the results, error messages, and a better description of what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments, here's an approach you can follow to accomplish test reporting and email results:

Consider leveraging `unittest` for test reporting - Selenium has [an example of this](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html#using-selenium-to-write-tests) in their docs.

Then, you can use `smtplib` to send emails. There are a myriad of resources for this; here's [one tutorial on `smtplib` with Gmail](https://pybit.es/python-smtplib.html).

---

In a nutshell:

1. Use `unittest` to set up a test suite
2. Access the test results via `unittest`'s API to do so
3. Build whatever string you want to send, and send it off with `smtplib`

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, it would be preferable to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: I provided links to sufficient tutorials for learning both how to integrate `unittest` and `selenium` as well as `smtplib`, but I believe providing an entire solution of doing so seems out of scope for a stack overflow post where the author has no specific issue or question and has not attempted to solve the problem at all. Should they make an attempt and encounter an issue, then addressing that issue would be in scope, but until then I think this gives them everything they need

Comment: Thanks buddy. Your theoretically answer works. It has much information @Hawkins.